# How to auto add desktop icon for all new likewise-open users

Tags: login, users

I want to add a desktop icon to the desktop of every user that logs in.

The system is connected to Active Directory using LikeWise-open, I don't want to manualy add the desktop icons to every user, then first every user has to log in to the system, and new users don't have it.

Is it possible to do this with a script that is triggered at a user login (Lightdm, session-setup-script=[script|command])?

But, I have now idea how to create a desktop icon using a script (or with the terminal for that matter).

I already have a `.desktop` file that is executable and does what it needs to do.

I'm running 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

When a new user logs in, his home directory is created by copying `/etc/skel/` to `/home/<username>/`.

You only have to create the directoy `/etc/skel/Desktop/` then put your `.desktop` file in there.